# docker-compose ERROR: .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: docker-compose, ubuntu-14.04

So when i run the command,

```
docker-compose -f config/somefile.yml up -d
```

I get the following error:
ERROR: .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ./config/somefile.yml

I tried giving the full path to the yml file, but the error is the same.

However, when i create a dulicate file with the name docker-compose.yml  (by using, script:  cp somefile.yml docker-compose.yml) and then i run

```
docker-compose up
```

It runs fine.
It just cannot run any other file than the default one.
Ive searched a lot of places and could not find any solution.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Docker-compose: 1.22
O.S: Ubuntu 14.4

Answer (score 33):

In my case, I forgot to start Docker itself.

So, check if you've started the Docker application before executing docker-compose.

Answer (score 3):

The file is probably not there.

One way to make sure the tool is not to blame, is to use another basic command like `cat`.

```sh
$ cat ./config/somefile.yml
cat: ./config/somefile.yml: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I see the file with `cat` but not with `docker-compose`

Answer (score 1):

For me, restarting both the Docker app and terminal worked.

[image: downloading]

Answer (score 0):

I had switched to a different git branch where the deployment files where missing. Later I switched back to my branch including it. Linux has lost the file reference and did not see the files anymore. `ls` was not showing anything. I had to leave the directory and enter it again. Then `docker-compose` could find the files again.

Answer (score 0):

The same as the others, my issue was solved by restarting the service using:
`docker compose restart`